# Помогите написать запрос

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте. У меня есть бд, в которой есть такие таблицы:
tennismatch, tennisset, game. Теннисный матч имеет(1:n) два или три сета. Сеты имеют(1:n) по несколько геймов. Так же есть промежуточные сгенерированные таблицы tennismatch_tennisset, tennisset_game.
Есть запрос, который выводит конечный счет всех геймов матча:

```
SELECT game.`FINALSCORE` FROM tennismatch JOIN
tennismatch_tennisset ON tennismatch.`ID` = tennismatch_tennisset.`TennisMatch_ID`
AND tennismatch.`ID` = 22130 JOIN
tennisset ON tennismatch_tennisset.`mapOfSets_ID` = tennisset.`ID`
JOIN tennisset_game ON tennisset.`ID` = tennisset_game.`TennisSet_ID` JOIN
game ON tennisset_game.`gamesMap_ID` = game.`ID`
```

У меня никак не получается написать запрос, который выдаст счет(finalscore) отдельно взятого гейма. К примеру первый(последний) гейм первого или второго сета. А так же отдельно геймы первого сета.

Comment: для начала придумайте критерий что такое "первый" или "последний" гейм. как именно определяется какой гейм первый ? когда определитесь добавьте соответствующее условие в where или подходящую сортировку и limit 1

Comment: "Первый" и "последний" гейм это первый и последний объект в коллекции Map.

Comment: причем тут коллекция map. как эти записи узнать в БД, они пронумерованы может быть или еще как нибудь ?

Comment: обратите внимание: до тех пор пока в запросе не указан порядок сортировки (order by) понятий "первый" и "последний" для БД в принципе не существует

Comment: При том, что при OneToMany relationship используется коллекция(в данном случае Map). Теннисный сет имеет коллекцию(Map) геймов которые расположены по порядку и каждый имеет свой индекс. Я просто не знаю как эти индексы получить в sql

Comment: Так, стоп, а вы эти самые индексы в БД пишите, когда информацию из программы сохраняете ? Как называется поле, в которое вы их записываете

Comment: Я записываю используя Java JPA. В Entity классе TennisSet поле геймов такое @OneToMany
    Map<Integer, Game> gamesMap ;

Comment: Да, но порядок записей при записи и последующем чтении ни чем не гарантирован. Вы же должны как то, когда потом из БД эту же коллекцию получаете явно задавать порядок записей, что бы записи в map опять оказались в том же порядке под теми же номерами